# Spring Security - Unauthorized though permitting all requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, unauthorized

I have such a web config in Spring Boot App:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

when trying to reach one of the urls (localhost:8080/test), I get Unauthorized. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My shot is that your `WebConfig` is [not placed in the right package](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code).
If your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in `com.example.demo`
then your `WebConfig` class should be placed under the `com.example.demo` package (or other sub-package, e.g: `com.example.demo.config`).

```java
package com.example.demo.config; // <-- move it to the (not-default) package

// skipped imports
// ...

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      // config same as in the question's snippet
      // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: By mistake I've created config package one level upper... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My shot it's related to " .httpBasic();", looks like you're expecting a basic authentication when you set this in your properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an Unauthorize (401) it means that the authentication failed, regardless of whether you have access to access the resource or not.
You are using basic auth, and the spring flow has two parts, authentication and authorization, first it authenticates, to know if a user is valid and then it is seen if they have authorization to access the resource. In this case the error is given because it does not have authentication, better known as 401, in case you had authentication and no authorization, you would receive a 403 forbiden

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to remove the context path from the properties file. I removed this:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

after I removed that value, then everything went right. But, I still don't know why it won't work with the context-path.